# serializer.is_valid() works with integer fields but serializer.save() asks for model instance

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a many-to-many relationship in ma database (PK are integers). I auto-generated django models from the db and implemented the simplest serializer.

When I give a dictionary with integers to the serializer, serializer.is_valid() returns True, but serializer.save() says fields should be models instances.

But when I give a dictionary with models instances, serializer.is_valid() returns False.

```
data = {'tag_id': 9, 'spending_id': 17}
serializer = TagspendingSerializer(data= data)
serializer.is_valid()
True
serializer.save()
```

=> ValueError: Cannot assign "9": "Tagspending.tag_id" must be a "Tag" instance.

```
data = {'tag_id': Tag.objects.get(tag_id= 9), 'spending_id': Spending.objects.get(spending_id= 17)}
serializer = TagspendingSerializer(data= data)
serializer.is_valid()
```

=> False

Here's my model :

```
class Tagspending(models.Model):
    tag_id = models.ForeignKey(Tag, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='tag_ID', primary_key=True)
    spending_id = models.ForeignKey(Spending, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='spending_ID')

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'TagSpending'
        unique_together = (('tag_id', 'spending_id'),)
```

Here's my serializer :

```
class TagspendingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tagspending
        fields = ('tag_id', 'spending_id')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there is something to make bit clearer for you

Django does this:

> ForeignKey defines an extra attribute with _id appended to the field name

You have the following field in your model:

```
tag_id = models.ForeignKey(Tag, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='tag_ID', primary_key=True)
```

But you don't really need to specify db column or primary key and do this instead:

```
tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, models.DO_NOTHING)
```

In db, the db column for this field will have the name tag_id ( like you would like ) and the type will be integer.
That's why the validation passes.

Now, you can access the id `instance.tag_id` or `instance.tag.id` ( however there is difference between this two calls - one hits the db if not already retrieved).

However, in your case 'tag_id' is ForeignKey and requires "Tag" instance.

You have 2 possible way to resolve this ( assuming that you use my suggested change to rename the field )

1) You can use tag_id in your post request ( now, with the field change name to `tag` )

2) in your serializer, you can specify the following:

```
tag = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Tag.objects.all())
```

and you can do post request with

```
{"tag" : 1 }
```

and this will resolve your id to the Tag instance ( if valid )

Comment: So now serializer.is_valid() returns True and serializer.save() returns another error : **django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column TagSpending.id does not exist**. Is it because TagSpending doesn't have primary key anymore ? Then how can I indicate to Django that (tag_id, spending_id) is the PK of the table ?

Comment: @SimonLejoly so you do the same with the other field too. it is the same.

Comment: I did. And I set tag primary_key to True. But I still get the error. (And Django is trying to inject (NULL, NULL) into the table, although I gave the serializer {'tag': 1, 'spending': 1}... Weird...)

Comment: nevermind. Your solution fixed the problem. Anyway, I now get a django.db.utils.IntegrityError as Django is trying to add a (NULL, NULL) row to the table. I don't get it as my serializer's data are still {'tag': 1, 'spending': 1} and it is declared as valid... Any help with this would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug with `Django Rest Framework`, due to your use of the `tag_id` as primary key.
You should change your model, and that's best practice, by altering the relation with a `Tag` as a `OneToOneField` (because it's a primary key, this relation is unique, therefore a `OneToOneField` is more fitting). Your serializer should work then.

You should also consider renaming your model fields. No need to introduce the '_id' suffix.

Comment: How do you modify 'tag_id = models.ForeignKey(Tag, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='tag_ID', primary_key=True)' so that it becomes a models.OneToOneField without disconnecting it from the database ?

Comment: I'm not sure what is your level of understanding of Django web framework, but just in case : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/migrations/ If this doesn't answer your question, please be more precise.

Comment: I'm new to DWF. The problem is that everything I found related to OneToOneField is there : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield. It doesn't describe how the model is linked to the database. As a trial, I edited my model with attribute 'tag_id = models.OneToOneField(Tag, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='tag_ID')', but then during makemigrations Django says I asked to add a field to the table and I should specify default value. So I guess that's not what I expected.

Comment: That's because you removed "primary_key=True", if you really intend to use this field as primary key, you should keep it that way, and Django will not ask you to specify a default value.